# SQL Query in Controller Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I need to excecute this SQL Query in a class Controller in symfony:

```
SELECT * FROM Announcement INNER JOIN User ON Announcement.userId=User.userId
```

It works fine on phpmyadmin and I tried to do it on my class controller like this:

```
$helpers = $this->get("app.helpers");
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Announcement INNER JOIN User ON Announcement.userId=User.userId FOR JSON AUTO");
$statement->execute();
return $helpers->json($statement->fetchAll());
```

But is returning `null`. What am I doing wrong. I'm new with symfony, so I don't know much.

Comment: You can't set a method in Annoucement repository who return a ->getArrayResult() and in your controller make a json_encode of the result?

Comment: and there is an intermediate result? `fetchAll` returns something?

Comment: "FOR JSON AUTO" works on mysql server?

Comment: Ok, sorry for not answering this, first, FOR JSON AUTO doesn't work on Mysql, and second, the code is ok, it was me all the time, I was entering the url wrong. I will just delete the question and hide. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score -1):

This is a way, not advisable but a way:

```
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Announcement INNER JOIN User ON Announcement.userId=User.userId FOR JSON AUTO";
    $conn = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $params = $conn->getParams();
    $paramHost = $params['host'];
    $paramPort = $params['port'];
    $paramDb = $params['dbname'];
    $paramUser = $params['user'];
    $paramPass = $params['password'];
    $myConn = "host=$paramHost port=$paramPort dbname=$paramDb user=$paramUser password=$paramPass";
    $conn = pg_connect($myConn);
    pg_query($sql);
    pg_close($conn);
```

Notice pg_ is for postgres, for mysql use mysqli_ instead